# Flutter: Add a new line in Text Widget

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, widget

I know there are a lot of questions like this but all those answers did not help me out.
I'm receiving two texts from my API backend and when I display them everything works just fine until one of these words are too long. I didn't manage to automatically jump to a new line in that case.
This is the relevant part of my code:

```
Text(
     item.brand + '\n' + item.model,
     style: const TextStyle(
     fontSize: 18,
     fontFamily: 'Avenir',
     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
     ),
```

Can someone please help me out? Thank you so much!

Comment: You should use two Text widgets or a RichText widget instead of having "\n"

Answer (score 3):

Try below code hope its helpful to you.

Declare Two `Text` widgets inside Column:

```
 Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text(
          'Your First Text', //just change your text like item.brand
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18,
            fontFamily: 'Avenir',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          'Your Second Text', //just change your text like item.model
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18,
            fontFamily: 'Avenir',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Your result screen using above widgets-> [image: Image 1]

Use `\n` also inside Text widget

```
Text(
          'Your First Text' + '\n' + 'Your Second Text',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18,
            fontFamily: 'Avenir',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question the right way, you want to jump to new line when the text is too long. In that case, you must wrap your text inside a parent widget with a define size, for example a SizedBox :

```dart
const SizedBox(
  height: 200,
  width: 200,
  child: Text(
     item.brand + '\n' + item.model,
     style: const TextStyle(
     fontSize: 18,
     fontFamily: 'Avenir',
     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
     ))
```

The text will now jump to a new line when it is longer than 200px

Comment: Thank for the answer, but that doesn't work for me because the text is inside of a Card widget. Depending on which phone the App is running on, I need different a width. and width: double.infinity also does not work, it shows an error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this answer your question but you can try use this widget below

```
Text.rich(TextSpan(
    text: "${item.brand}\n",
    style: const TextStyle(
        fontSize: 18, fontFamily: 'Avenir', fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    children: [
      TextSpan(
        text: "${item.model}",
        style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18,
            fontFamily: 'Avenir',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
    ]));
```

In this widget you can add diferents styles in your texts, and by using the `${}` operator allows you to break the line with `\n`.
Or you can just do this inside your `Text` widget.

```
Text(
     "${item.brand}\n${item.model}",
     style: const TextStyle(
     fontSize: 18,
     fontFamily: 'Avenir',
     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
     ),
```

In dart you can use the + operator to concatenate Strings, but it's not necessary